# Set a code to SQL server and show in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

i decided to code a contact program which will connect to SQL server.
Nearly i have completed to codes and program runs good.
But i have a problem.
When user wants to delete a contact from this program , he should enter Family Name of contact whom he wants to delete then press Delete button in the form.
Well this way is not very good because it is possible that there were for example 5 guys with the same family name.
i decided to Add a field in the SQL server in the name of Code.
This code is unique for every contacts.
But i have a problem. how should i code program that whenever user type the information of contact and click save , this unique code add automatically to the Code field in the SQL server ?
here is my codes you can see :

```
namespace Contact
{
    class Operation
    {
        SqlConnection cn;
        public Operation()
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(Connection.Server);
        }

        public DataTable Show()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblContact ", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            return dt;
        }

        public void Add(string Name , string FamilyName , string Work , string Fax , string Phone , string Home)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblContact(Name,FamilyName,Work,Fax,Phone,Home) values ('" + Name + "' , '" + FamilyName + "' , '" + Work + "' , '" + Fax + "' , '" + Phone + "' , '" + Home + "')", cn);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
        public void Delete(string FamilyName)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblContact where FamilyName = '" + FamilyName + "'", cn);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }

        public void Update (string Name , string FamilyName , string Work , string Fax , string Phone , string Home)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblContact set FamilyName = '" + FamilyName + "' ,Work = '" + Work + "' , Fax = '" + Fax + "' , Name = '" + Name + "' , Home = '" + Home + "' where Phone = '" + Phone + "'",cn);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Search about [IDENTITY columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). And after that look at how to write a parameterized query. Your code is an free pass for every hacker

Comment: if you are allowing a user to select from a DataGridView then pull back all the columns you need hide the Identity key field of the DataGridView, and when the user Selects a Row.. then you do a `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.SelectedRows)` then you can capture the KeyId for example and delete from the table where KeyId= the Selected KeyId from the `row.Cells[0].Value`

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries immediately. This is wide open to sql injection. And you really should avoid using select * unless it is inside an EXISTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For having a unique column in a table, the best way is to create a column (Named `ID` for exmaple) with `int` type or `bigint` and set the `Identity` property to true. In this case you have a column that the value is started from 1 and increments automatically for each new row. You can set this column to primary key too, because it is unique and not null.

Then for delete purpose you can use this column only.

```
DELETE FROM tblContact WHERE ID = (Your Parameter)
```

Just set the Parameter.

You should first find deleting row based on familyname or any other column, then get the ID value from that row and call delete for that row.

The better way for this purpose is that you show the list of contacts to the user (in a grid for example and hide the ID column) and the user selects the row for delete. At that time you have the ID from that row and pass that to this function:

```
public void Delete(int ID)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblContact where ID = " + ID + "'", cn);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```